# Python curses - can't get TAB key

Tags: python, key, ncurses

I need to catch TAB key in Python. For any other keys I do:

```
x = self.myscreen.getch()
if( x == curses.KEY_DOWN ):
  # and so..
```

What's the constant for TAB key? I searched [here](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html) (bottom of page) and tried every *TAB* contant.

I tried '\t' too. Is it possible? Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
if ( x == ord('\t')):
    ...
```

or

```
if ( x == 9):
    ...
```

You need to be sure to convert the character to an integer with ord() before comparing to the value from getch

Answer (score -3):

Try [this](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=850) it looks like what your asking For

Comment: that looks promising.  I think once i had this kinda problem and needed a really quick dirty solution. I think I inputted the character and saved the object with pickle, and every time I would compare to that pickled objects value. not very nice though!

Comment: I need to catch tab key in python. In your example is catching tab key in *.vim file. That's different. Maybe I am blind :) Can you please be more specific?

Comment: well according to the site you need to add - The Vim plugin that creates the Tab-completion functionality for Python files.

Comment: Maybe I am dumb, but why I need Vim? I am not using Vim! I am not creating plugin for Vim.

Comment: i looked on the link u provided and i didnt see any TAB inputs - could you explain better on what you mean by "constant"

Comment: You need explain the response.